# PHP socket_connect Stack Overflow

Tags: php

In the desciption of the vulnerability:

```
Stack-based buffer overflow in the socket_connect function in ext/sockets/sockets.c 
in PHP 5.3.3 through 5.3.6 might allow context-dependent attackers to execute 
arbitrary code via a long pathname for a UNIX socket.
```

I can see how this might be a local issue, but how could an attacker potentially exploit this remotely?

EDIT:

Exact vulnerability: http://www.securityfocus.com/bid/47950

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The exploit for this vulnerability](http://downloads.securityfocus.com/vulnerabilities/exploits/47950-2.php) turns the address argument in socket_connect() function into a sink that can be used to obtain code execution.   In one attack scenario this vulnerability turns socket_connect() into a very serious [exploitable php function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115559/exploitable-php-functions/3697776#3697776).   This attack could be used against an application like [PHPProxy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpproxy/),  where the attacker can control what address the application is connecting to.

However buffer overflows in PHP functions are more likely used in the post-exploitation phase of an attack.  After the attacker compromises your system he can then use an exploit like the one above to bypass [PHP safe_mode](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php) restrictions or [disable_functions](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-apache-lighttpd-phpini-disable-functions/) php.ini setting.  For example, even if the `system()` function is disabled, a buffer overflow can still be used to drop the attacker to a shell.   **[PHP safe_mode bypass exploits are very common](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:http://www.exploit-db.com%2520safemode%2520bypass&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a#hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=Rwa&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&sclient=psy-ab&q=site:http://www.exploit-db.com%20safe%20mode%20bypass&oq=site:http://www.exploit-db.com%20safe%20mode%20bypass&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=serp.3...4389l4389l1l4705l1l1l0l0l0l0l242l242l2-1l1l0.frgbld.&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=127b2022ec684f4c&biw=1680&bih=899)**,  and that is the major reason why its being removed from the language.

Comment: So the only web servers in danger of being exploited are ones that allow users to somehow interact with the socket_connect() function, which would be quite rare?

Comment: @Bhubhu Hbuhdbus No,  its mostly used for post-exploitation.  I have updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not intimately familiar with the details of this vulnerability, and you didn't link to any further information about it, but just based upon the information provided here:

If your PHP code allows remote users to influence the contents of the Unix socket pathname (something that may be rare, but perhaps not completely implausible), then a malicious remote user may plausibly be able to use their influence on the pathname to exploit the vulnerability.